# How do you perform mouse movements & clicks virtually [user32.dll]

Tags: c#, winapi

How do you perform mouse movements & clicks virtually ?

What I mean by virtually is that, the main mouse isn't affected, so basically "creating" a second mouse that is controlled by setting x/y position (pref with user32.dll).

I have read a few similar questions here but the answer usually is with your main mouse, Example:

```
DllImport("user32")]
public static extern int SetCursorPos(int x, int y);
```

^ this moves your main mouse to x&y position on screen, what I want is to perform this action with a "virtual mouse" so my main mouse isn't moved, so basically I can keep using my computer while this "virtual mouse" does something else in another window for example.

then using this "virtual mouse" to perform clicks [[virtual key codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes?redirectedfrom=MSDN)]

I have tried this:

```
IntPtr MakeLParam(int x, int y) => (IntPtr)((y << 16) | (x & 0xFFFF));
            
var pointPtr = MakeLParam(900, 1000);//x y cords 
           
IntPtr hWnd = ScreenCapture.FindWindow(null, ScreenCapture.GetWindowName()); //Finds Window 

PostMessage(hWnd, WM_MOUSEMOVE | WM_LBUTTONDOWN | WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, pointPtr);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern Int32 PostMessage(
            IntPtr hWnd,               // handle to destination window
            int Msg,                // message
            IntPtr wParam,             // first message parameter
            IntPtr lParam);            // second message parameter
```

But nothing happens at all, and my guess is that WM_MOUSEMOVE is not working properly

```
public const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
        public const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
        public const int WM_COMMAND = 0x111;
        public const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;
        public const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x202;
        public const int WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x203;
        public const int WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x204;
        public const int WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x205;
        public const int WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x206;
        public const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;
```

UPDATE, I think I solved it somewhat !

After reading more about PostMessage /SendInput, I found out that "application windows" can have layers of "application windows", so I used ispy++ to check it out, and yes the program had another layer where I wanted to click.

So to solve this I took the class name of the window where I wanted to click as well as the window name, here is an example code:

```
 public static bool ClickTest()
        {
            IntPtr MakeLParam(int x, int y) => (IntPtr)((y << 16) | (x & 0xFFFF));//Just converts x&y to InPtr lParam

            IntPtr WindowhWid = ScreenCapture.FindWindow(null, ScreenCapture.GetWindowName()); //Gets the window hWid
            var ClasshWid = FindWindowEx(WindowhWid, IntPtr.Zero, "Classname", null); //Gets the Class hWid using WindowhWid AND the Class name (Need to find a way to get the classname using process list)

            PostMessage(ClasshWid, WM_LBUTTONDOWN | WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, MakeLParam(938, 1011));//Finally sends it to the classhWid

            return true;
        }
```

Using these two functions

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern int FindWindowEx(
            IntPtr hwndParent, 
            IntPtr hwndChildAfter,
            string strClassName,
            string strWindowName);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern Int32 PostMessage(
            int hWnd,               // handle to destination window
            int Msg,                // message
            int wParam,             // first message parameter
            IntPtr lParam);            // second message parameter
```

Note that it won't click if the appilication window is MINIMIZED, although it will click if the window is behind another appilication window !

Also the X & Y is the screen X & Y and not the Application X & Y !

Now the question remains, why doesn't it work while the application window is minimized ?

The click doesn't go anywhere but to the application, so shouldn't it work while the application is minimized ?

Comment: See [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput)

Comment: Are you determined to work at this rough/raw level of pretending to move a mouse, click, etc? If possible, move up a semantic level or two and work with [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/).

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513). The same underlying principles apply to mouse input. The sane alternative has been [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65237419/how-do-you-perform-mouse-movements-clicks-virtually-user32-dll#comment115333447_65237419) earlier.

Comment: @IInspectable so how do "bot" programs do it ?, do they use a virtual machine ?

Comment: I don't know which particular *"bot"* you are referring to, so I cannot answer that question. It's wildly unclear what a *"virtual machine"* has **anything** to do with this.

Comment: By "virtual machine" I mean a windows vm where the program is executed and using the vm's mouse and keyboard and not your mouse & keyboard

Comment: 1. *the X & Y is the screen X & Y and not the Application X & Y* According to the documentation, the coordinates in `WM_LBUTTONDOWN/WM_LBUTTONUP` are relative to the upper-left corner of the client area. 2. `WM_LBUTTONDOWN | WM_LBUTTONUP`=0x203 The actual message you send is `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK`, you need to post the message separately. 3. As comment pointed out: simulate keyboard input with `PostMessage` is not reliable.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT Well using xy of the appliction doesn't work for me atleast, the screen xy works fine. And there is apparently no other way than postmessage method. But if you have another way please let me know !

Comment: For all similar problems, the choice is [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/)

Comment: @jejejeje1 there's no need to use mouse events in 99.99999999999% of cases. Windows exposes UI elements and events programmatically to enable accessibility utilities and devices since the 1990s. As for WM_MOUSEMOVE not working - if it didn't Windows wouldn't work either. This is a fundamental message. One that's *not* needed if you want to automate a drag operation though. There are specific Drag&drop messages like [WM_DROPFILES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/wm-dropfiles)

Comment: `there is apparently no other way than postmessage` on the contrary, the accessibility APIs work for 20+ years.

Answer (score -3):

It migiht not be what you're up to and what you look after, but [AutoIT Dll](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/177167-using-autoitx-from-c-net/) offers plenty of automation ready to use and in the easiest way possible. Since you rely on a windows DLL then it's perfect.

If you're still on your own way to user32.dll then check [Low level hook](https://github.com/mwinapi/mwinapi/blob/master/ManagedWinapi/Hooks/LowLevelHook.cs), that's what I used.

I highly recommend AutoIT dll though, it will save you ton of hair pulling hours guessing what's happening to the windows messages that do not respond properly

Comment: A [low-level mouse hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644986(v=vs.85)) allows you to *monitor* mouse input. It's unclear how you would propose to use it to *inject* mouse input.

Comment: @IInspectable the same way it monitors, it can be used to create input.

Comment: That's like saying *"you write to read-only memory the same way you read from it"*. Clearly, that doesn't make sense. A low-level mouse hook can monitor mouse input only (and optionally filter it from further processing). And that's all it does.

Comment: I did. There's nothing special. It's a managed wrapper for low-level keyboard and mouse hooks, like hundreds and thousands of others have done before. Nothing in the code indicates that a hook were capable of generating input. There's an implementation of [`InjectKeyboardEvent`](https://github.com/mwinapi/mwinapi/blob/a1bac7377c3dc176f8163fd392711348eaf7a358/ManagedWinapi/KeyboardKey.cs#L127) elsewhere in the same source repository. That's unrelated to hooks, though, and a pretty broken implementation, too.

Comment: I read it well enough to explain what the code does. Which part of my explanation do you disagree with?

Comment: @IInspectable You didn't. I disagree in the part you say with the code provided you can't recreate mouse actions. I got a warning to "avoid extended disussions in comments". So I would end it here. I did my work with that library some time ago. If you can't it's not my problem and it's out of the scope of this question

Comment: The input injection code is neither part of the low-level hook implementations, nor is it implemented by means of hooks (which, as we have established already, cannot be done anyway). If you used this library, and are happy with it, then that's good for you. Someone with stricter correctness requirements is likely going to avoid it, though.